# sharing a tuple type in a discriminated union

Tags: f#, set, sequence, dry

suppose we have

```ml
type MyTuples =
    | One of a: string * b: string * c: string
    | Two of a: string * b: string * c: string * d: string
    | Three of a: string * b: string * c: string * e: string * f: int
```

Would it not be possible to share `a: string * b: string * c: string` among the cases of the DU?

Perhaps like this:

```ml
type MyOne = One of a: string * b: string * c: string // the single-case DU

type MySharingTuples =
    | One of MyOne
    | Two of MyOne * d: string
    | Three of MyOne * e: string * f: int

let myTwo = MyTuples.Two (a = "1", b = "2", c = "3", d = "4")

let mySharingTwo = MySharingTuples.Two (MyOne.One (a = "1", b = "2", c = "3"), d = "4")

myTwo |> printfn "%A"
mySharingTwo |> printfn "%A"
```

which prints

```
Two ("1", "2", "3", "4")
Two (One ("1", "2", "3"), "4")
```

From a type theory perspective, `myTwo` and `mySharingTwo` are not equal and the compiler will not even allow us to prove that at runtime. But from a set theory perspective, `Two ("1", "2", "3", "4")` and `Two (One ("1", "2", "3"), "4")` look like:

```
("1", "2", "3", "4") = (("1", "2", "3"), "4")
```

which my old math books tell me there is equivalency up there.

Does `MyTuples` violate the DRY pinciple? Is there some way show that, say, `MyOne` is equivalent to `MyTuples.One`? Does this investigation even have any point? Am i mixing up type theory and set theory here and confusing myself?

Comment: No, you cannot alias part of a tuple. Consider modeling your data with records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think that your original `MyTuples` violates the DRY principle and that Fyodor's suggestion to use a common record type instead is the best approach:

```ml
type Shared = { a: string; b: string; c: string }

type MyTuples =
    | One of Shared
    | Two of Shared * d: string
    | Three of Shared * e: string * f: int

    with
    member this.Shared =
        match this with
            | One shared -> shared
            | Two (shared, _) -> shared
            | Three (shared, _, _) -> shared
```

You can then share the common component, like this:

```ml
let myTwo = MyTuples.Two ({ a = "1"; b = "2"; c = "3" }, d = "4")
let myThree = Three (myTwo.Shared, e = "5", f = 6)
```

Comment: i accept this as the answer because F# does not support extending a record type with another record type (we can intersect like this in Typescript with `&`); we have to use this brilliant mixture of records and tuples in order for things like `match` (pattern matching) to work in F#

Answer (score 2):

> Does MyTuples violate the DRY pinciple?

I think without more context, there isn't a clear answer to this question.

The Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle only really applies to situations where both code and *context* is repeated. Here, we don't have context. Is `a` the thing that's contextually repeated across your union clauses, is `a, b` the repeated thing, is it `a, b, c`, or is it none of them? Without more context, I think the suggestion of using records is a nice one. However, if these things are indeed related (for example, they could be representing 3, 4, 5-dimensional vectors), then you could use anonymous records inside the discriminated union. For example:

```
type MyTuples =
    | One of {| a: string; b: string; c: string|}
    | Two of {| a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string |}
    | Three of {| a: string; b: string; c: string; e: string; f: int |}

let one = One {|a="a"; b="b"; c="c"|}
```

> Is there some way show that, say, MyOne is equivalent to MyTuples.One?

Yes, you could define a comparison function or functions or even operators.

> Does this investigation even have any point? Am i mixing up type theory and set theory here and confusing myself?

I don't think it's much of an investigation. Types are meant to help you model some domain. Without the context of a domain, the only question really here is is a technical one about if F# allows one to extend an existing record definition, and the answer is no.

It isn't clear to me how set and type theory are relevant.

Comment: Can you explain for everyone why you use anonymous record? I guess it's because we can write `{| abc with d="d" |}` having `let abc = {|a="a"; b="b"; c="c"|}` hence some (pseudo?) type extension.

Comment: your answer _no_ is most sufficient for me :) ; the most context i can write up is in my [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/BryanWilhite/jupyter-central/blob/master/funkykb/fsharp/discriminated-unions/sharing-tuples-or-records.ipynb)

Comment: @RomainDeneau There's no exact reason. In this case, it's just so that I didn't have to name the records with their own type definition. One particular though is having repeat names. For example, if I have a `type TwoVector = {x: float; y: float}` and a `type ThreeVector = {x: float; y: float; z: float}`, and then I want to define a single vector type, then I'd have to do something like `type Vector = | TwoVector of TwoVector | ThreeVector of ThreeVector`. This is valid F#, but you have types and constructors with the same names. I do typically do this though since there isn't another way.